# Wordpress com CF7 gravando em MySql externo

Tags: php, wordpress, formulário

Dentro de um WP tenho um formulário CF7 e preciso que os campos (normalmente estão [desta forma] como padrão de variável no CF7) sejam enviados para uma página externa PHP que vai receber estes valores através do link e gravar no banco em outro local. Algo mais ou menos assim:

- Form CF7 com dados [nome] [email] [endereco]
- Usar o campo de script ou de redirecionamento do CF7 para capturar estas variaveis CF7 [nome] [email] [endereco]
- Criar o link http://meusite.com/recebedados.php?nome=[nome]&email=[email]&endereco=[endereco]
- Concluir operação com o envio do form e o envio deste link para página externa PHP que vai gravar em outro MySql

--> pontos importantes:
- Não quero usar o banco de dados do plugin local;
- Preciso gravar em BD externo (outra hospedagem);
- Pode ser utilizado o campo de script quanto o de direcionamento que já vem no CF7, porém precisa passar estas [variaveis] no link;

Muito obrigado pelas indicações ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido
Utilizei o recurso do CF7 de pegar suas variáveis e enviar para um redirecionamento através do link. 
Na página destino resgatei-as e usei no banco como precisava.